# Space navigation evenly across window (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to space my navigation evenly across the top of my page while eliminated any empty space on the left, right, and between each link. I know I could probably just use the Calc function but it is not supported enough with older versions of browsers so I am looking for an alternative method.

My current code:

```css
.nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #252839;
 }

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav ul li{
  color:  #b5b5b7;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #677077;
  color: #89C4F4;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <a href="#home"><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href="#profile"><li>Profile</li></a>
    <a href="#experience"><li>Experience</li></a>
    <a href="#abilities"><li>Abilities</li></a>
    <a href="#projects"><li>Projects</li></a>
    <a href="#contact"><li>Contact</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Only `li` elements should be a direct child of `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [display:flex](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and `flex-grow: 1` to expand the `li` elements, then change the `a` tags within to `display: block` and center the text.

```css
.nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #252839;
 }

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.nav ul li{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color:  #b5b5b7;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #677077;
  color: #89C4F4;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abilities">Abilities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure that works ,but it doesn't give me the full hover effect that I like. it only highlights to portion behind the text. I've tried using a padding of 0 100%; but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to make a few more changes, starting with putting your `a` inside the `li` where it should be. Updated answer.